Entra joined device seamless SSO not working for on premise web app configured for Windows authentication on https
Our device is Entra registered and has line of sight to our Active Directory Domain Controller. We have passwordless authentication setup using FIDO security key per the following microsoft site,
Seamless SSO is working for Windows authentication-based services such as SSMS and network shares, but is not working for our web app configured for Windows Authentication in IIS. The browser prompts for a username and password. There is no password that can be entered, and the dialog does not provide an option to enter the PIN for the FIDO security key.
I configured Windows Authentication to prioritize NTLM over negotiate, removing negotiate entirely but to no avail. The browser prompts for passwords even when accessing the application on the IIS server itself.
The issue occurs in  Edge, Chrome and Firefox. The laptop is Windows 11, and server version is Windows Server 2022.
What am I missing? What can I debug to check where the issues are?

Update
After adding entra id to Site Zone assignment list in the group policy, as described here, SSO started working on http without the password prompt, but on https, it gives me unauthorized, invalid credentials without asking for a password prompt. I have tried adding the domain with https to the group policy but to no avail.
Any pointers on what I can troubleshoot would be really helpful.

What am I missing? when a browser connects to the site, a 401 is returned. This results in the browser adding the W3 authorization header to the request. You first need to confirm that the header is sent. Probably using Fiddler or equivalent.

I understand that, my question is why is the correct authorization headers not being sent given that seamless SSO should work automatically as stated by microsoft here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-authentication-passwordless-troubleshoot

I don't think you understand. The browser must send an authentication header. It 100% is not sending the header. There are many possible reasons, usually related to the client endpoint not being configured to send the credentials, which it will not do by default.

My point is that as per Microsoft, the client should send them by default once they are entra joined. Could you guide me towards what specifically should I troubleshoot or look at?

the client should send them by default once they are entra joined. not accurate. Any client endpoint needs to be configured to automatically offer up credentials without prompting the user. You aren't going to get anywhere by not even checking for obvious basic headers and saying Microsoft says it should work. And you should test with a regular account without security key due to even with a simple configuration you are struggling with basic concepts. The security key will only be a bright shiny object to distract you.

Do you have actionable steps that I can follow otherwise this conversation isn’t going anywhere.

While Entra ID does provide Seamless SSO to get access to on-premise resources (as long as there is a line of sight to the domain controller from the connecting PC), there are a few configuration elements that are easy to overlook.

You MUST configure Microsoft Edge group policies to add https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com in the AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist and AuthServerAllowlist policy settings. The documentation gives the feeling that this step is optional but it is required. If you do not have the Edge group policy, you must download and set it up separately following instructions on this link.
In the same policy settings, you must also add your domain. For example, if your domain is X.com or Y.X.com, then the group policy should read like *X.com,*Y.X.com,https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com. If you do not add subdomains (like in my case) then windows auth will NOT work over SSL. Make sure you restart edge whenever you update them just to make sure these take effect.

With these steps, windows auth works perfectly to on-premise webservers for Entra Joined devices.
